# Matching BigDecimal with JSON Value - Java

Tags: java, json

I have some code below that pulls the values of 3 cards from a response. 
These values are between 0-51.

I have a JSON file in the project that determines which value is for which card. 
You can see the json here [Cards.json](https://api.myjson.com/bins/120v1v)

Here is the code which gets the values from the response:

```
private String[] CardAnalysis() throws Throwable {
    String cards = response.getBody().split("&cards=")[1]
            .split("&winID=")[0];
    String[] cardValues = cards.split(",");
    String card1 = cardValues[0];
    Card1 = new BigDecimal(Double.valueOf(card1));
    String card2 = cardValues[1];
    Card2 = new BigDecimal(Double.valueOf(card2));
    String card3 = cardValues[2];
    Card3 = new BigDecimal(Double.valueOf(card3));

    return cardValues;

}
```

I need the then match the values of Card1, Card2, Card3 and return what the cards actually are based on the JSON file.

Comment: Why are you using `BigDecimal` for values between 0 and 51? And why don't you just use a json mapper such as Jackson, Gson etc. to parse the json? And finally what's the problem with matching the values and returning the matched cards?

Comment: Oh and btw: instead of `new BigDecimal(Double.valueOf(card1))` you'd better use `new BigDecimal(card1)` - no need to add `Double` in there. On another though, why are you using decimal numbers such as BigDecimal or Double when you're basically dealing with integers?

Comment: Thats a fair comment, if you can point me in the right direction and give me a better option to do it I am more than happy to listen.

Comment: What pointer do you need? Just have a look at those Java-Json mappers I mentioned and pick one.

Comment: No worries, I will have a look at Jackson JSON mapper.